# How to store a numpy.ndarray into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, pickle

I'm trying to store a python numpy.ndarray into a MySQL table, using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713062/store-numpy-array-in-mysql).

When I use `ndarray.dumps()` I get back a the pickle object in bytes representation and when I try to store it in a BLOB MySQL data type I get a MySQL error. Here is the query:

```
> query = 'INSERT INTO user (loyalty_member_id, user_vector) VALUES ({0}, {1});'.format(user, user_vector)
```

where `user` is an INT and `user_vector` is the result of `numpy.ndarray.dumps()`