# What's the most efficient way to stor/retrieve a numpy array to mysql by python?

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, numpy, mysql-python

I'm using MySQL db and Python. I running some face recognition queries such as below:

```
for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
    matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
    face_Dis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
    # print(face_Dis)
    matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
```

I need to store the `matchIndex` numpy array into MySQL db and retrieve it to compare it with the real-time result coming from video stream.

As example for one face array as below:

```
[array([-0.03982568,  0.0466256 ,  0.10839709, -0.04618508, -0.18365356,
        0.01487046, -0.02441945, -0.11297068,  0.17233874, -0.04669763,
        0.29686055, -0.03716658, -0.26820186,  0.00475622, -0.03315876,
        0.11188678, -0.17055775, -0.11814106, -0.04149977, -0.12335332,
        0.10478698,  0.07871094, -0.0245239 , -0.05221708, -0.11528996,
       -0.29134476, -0.11530365, -0.05149739,  0.1486412 , -0.07742441,
        0.03924546,  0.08309049, -0.18108843, -0.07448926,  0.0588475 ,
       -0.00206966, -0.07270631, -0.09870195,  0.19136742, -0.01333379,
       -0.16585402, -0.06306425,  0.03135228,  0.15242851,  0.12671986,
        0.06151334,  0.02930382, -0.10507341,  0.05431183, -0.21889399,
        0.0982563 ,  0.19636418,  0.08638678,  0.04246487,  0.10104641,
       -0.21091488, -0.00053184,  0.19133894, -0.15123004,  0.09692279,
        0.10679097, -0.0997081 , -0.02019324, -0.05096144,  0.129476  ,
        0.02539396, -0.04582587, -0.19065364,  0.21564247, -0.07370852,
       -0.11738002,  0.13342284, -0.12635913, -0.16233116, -0.27765995,
       -0.00732662,  0.50213826,  0.02980643, -0.2086312 ,  0.01042579,
       -0.00930636, -0.02900947,  0.14645986,  0.0320985 , -0.03112174,
       -0.09587738, -0.15909459, -0.0389645 ,  0.19932204, -0.03060728,
       -0.05045725,  0.2260851 , -0.00543171,  0.05067419,  0.07360222,
        0.09129907, -0.04530992, -0.00215137, -0.0877424 , -0.06189177,
        0.05106816, -0.06142666, -0.08767837,  0.14337413, -0.12626182,
        0.15789033, -0.00425556,  0.01465969, -0.06580043, -0.11303413,
       -0.06203099,  0.03172189,  0.20761757, -0.2837159 ,  0.16302592,
        0.16049571, -0.01303555,  0.14014119,  0.03616813,  0.04973216,
        0.00611662, -0.11366641, -0.26029304, -0.10216802, -0.00345476,
       -0.0911523 , -0.042996  ,  0.04715518])
```

Comment: One way is to store the array as a blob dtype.  Essentially, you’ll convert the array to a binary string and store.  On retrieval, decode the binary string into a numpy array.

Comment: thanks dear, appreciate if you can you show me an example to the save load python code, so I will start from there.

Comment: Dear? No. That aside, have a look here at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38279703/6340496).

Comment: I see, thanks very much for your update, I'll try it tomorrow