# How to save numpy arrays with pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, pymysql

Is there a way to save numpy arrays (ideally in compressed form) into a MySQL database with pymysql?  I understand how to save numbers and strings, but how do query strings work with byte objects?  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [store numpy array in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713062/store-numpy-array-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure!  I can convert the numpy array to bytes, but how do I put the bytes into the query?  (This question was also asked in the link you sent.)